# How to get an IObservable back from Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, system.reactive

I have a simple Web API which returns an Iobservable. I am using HttpClient to get the Observable so that I can subscribe to it. My problem is the returned Iobservable on subscription sends out an 'empty' result.

SERVER

```cs
public IObservable<DataItem> GetDataItems()
{
    return Observable.Generate(0, i => i < 10, i => i + 1, 
        i => new DataItem 
        {
            Id = i, 
            Name = String.Format("Storage{0}",i)
        });
}
```

CLIENT

```cs
public IObservable<DataItem> GetDataItems()
{
    using (HttpClient apiClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9001");
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-authentication", "xxxxxx");
        return apiClient
            .GetAsync("api/xxxx/yyyy").Result.Content
            .ReadAsAsync<DataItem>().ToObservable();
    }
}

var source = GetDataItems();

List<DataItem> items = new List<DataItem>();

IDisposable consoleSubscription = source.Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", x.Id, x.Name),
            ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError : {0} ", ex.Message),
            () =>  Console.WriteLine("Encountered End of Stream")
            );
        consoleSubscription.Dispose();
```

My issue is I am not getting any data back from the server. I get an 'Empty' observable. I wrote a unit test against my controller and it does give back the dataitems.

Any suggestions please help. Unable to understand where I am going wrong. There are no errors on server or client.

Answer (score 21):

You're being a little ambitious expecting an `IObservable<T>` to be streamed over the wire automatically. I'm afraid WebAPI won't do that for you.

What you are seeing is the consequence of the default json serializer outputting the properties of `IObservable<T>` - and there are none so you get empty braces.

Your unit test works because it's all in-memory - no serialization/deserialization is happening.

There are ways of using HttpResponseMessage's StreamContent property to stream results out which you *could* bridge to/from `IObservable<T>` - but it's not really idiomatic WebApi. WebApi's async support is really aimed at asynchronous processing of requests with single-item responses on the server, not at returning continuously streaming events.

Bottom line is that I think WebApi (at least at the time of writing) is the wrong technology choice here. You are far better off looking at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20) which is purpose built for this sort of scenario, and is included in the current release of ASP.NET. It has both javascript and .NET client support, and you can bridge to `IObservable<T>` fairly easily. Some people have already looked at this, such as [in this post sporting example code](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/SignalR-and-Reactive-Extensions-are-an-Rx-for-server-push-notifications).

Some messaging middleware like my-Channels [Nirvana](http://um.terracotta.org) (*Edit: since bought out by Terracotta and wrapped into Universal Messaging* Some [example code](http://um.terracotta.org/#page/%2Fum.terracotta.org%2Funiversal-messaging-webhelp%2Fre-csharp_mychannels_rx_queue_consumer.html%23) is available in their documentation.), and CEP solutions like SQL Server [StreamInsight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362541%28SQL.111%29.aspx) have out of box `IObservable` support too.

Comment: Fixed the link-rot on the Nirvana link; Terracotta bought it.