# Web API Rx Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, system.reactive

I am currently trying to work through an example of building a Functional Reactive API similar to Netflix as partially defined by Ben Christensen [here](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/02/rxjava-netflix-api.html).

I setup a default ASP.NET Web API project and added a controller for retrieving a user like so:

```cs
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/user
    public IObservable<User> Get()
    {
        var temp = new User { FirstName = "Keith", LastName = "LaForce" };
        return Observable.Create<User>(

            (IObserver<User> observer) =>
            {
                observer.OnNext(temp);
                observer.OnCompleted();
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
                //or can return an Action like 
                //return () => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"); 
            });
    }
}
```

I am then trying to make a call utilizing RxJS to process this Observable API method with the following code:

```js
function getValues() {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://url-where-api-lives/api/user'
    }).promise();
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise);
};

var suggestions = getValues();

suggestions.subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function (e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

My console.log in the JS only ever prints out an empty Object {}.  My question is, how do you properly return an Rx Observable from an WebAPI controller and how do you process the results from the client?  Are you not able to do this, but rather the WebAPI should return an Enumerable and the Service Layer should be in charge of asynchronous work and return an Observable?

Comment: As these things go, I found the answer soon after posting.  Here is a similar question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230561/how-to-get-an-iobservable-back-from-web-api?rq=1

Comment: Voted to close with a link as result... bit mean not voting that answer up though! ;)