# Get Http Request with pause between every result from the lit

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, time, get

I want to build a simple API which just displays some data using the controller. The controller displays some dummy data using genfu and at the moment it is all retrieved at once, what i need to do is display each record after a certain amount of time, like, the first time i run the application i want 0 results, than, after one sec for example, the next one and so on, here's what i have so far in the controller, it's really really basic

```
// GET: api/<controller>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Contact> Get()
        {

         
            var data = _contactsGeneratorService.Collection(100);
            

            return data;
        }
```

I tried to use the thread.sleep option but it doesn't work in this case. Sorry, I am really really new to this.

Comment: I trust the API is not the right choice, you may consider SignalR, check the this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230561/how-to-get-an-iobservable-back-from-web-api?rq=1

Comment: Really unclear what you want to achieve and what behavior you want to see on server side (where your controller runs) vs. client side. To me it sounds like you want to emulate incremental loading of data to UI (for which you probably should look into paging the response from server, possibly with arificial slow down with Task.Delay on each call server side), but based on current answer it is far from only interpretation of the question.

Comment: From your description, you want to display the record one by one. If you are creating a timer and load the records on the server side (in the API controller), after that you need to send the each result to the client side and update the content, in this scenario, you could consider to use SignalR, it could used to achieve the real time update. Besides, you could also try to create a JQuery Timer and call the API method every one second, in the Ajax success function dynamically add a record in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the C# Timer Control/Class.  Here is an example from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0):

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
   private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
      SetTimer();

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
      Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.ReadLine();
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();
  
      Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
   }

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

For more examples, see this article: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/timer-cs.htm